# How to subset a large SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

Tags: r, r-sp

I want to calculate the area of a wildfire. I tried this by substracting the NDVI calculated on a Landsat image before and another image after the fire and see where the NDVI was reduced. However, not only in the burning areas the NDVI has changed, but there are also many random differences. I used *rasterToPolygons* to create a *large SpatialPolygonsDataFrame* containing all areas where NDVI after - NDVI before < 0.
Now I want to remove all the polygons with an area below a certain threshold value. However, I cannot find a way to subset the large SpatialPolygonsDataFrame.

I found an example on how to get a list of the polygons with an area above the threshold (where *burned_poly* is the *large SpatialPolygonsDataFrame*):

```
pols <- lapply(burned_poly@polygons , slot , "Polygons")
pols_areas <- lapply(pols[[2]], function(x) slot(x, "area"))
```

However, accessing the large SpatialPolygonsDataFrame like this

```
bp <- burned_poly@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[pols_areas >= 9000]
```

gives me a list which I am currently unable to coerce into a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame.

Can someone tell me how to do this last step (I have trouble with the *Sf* argument of which I don't know what it is in the *SpatialPolygonsDataFrame* function), or maybe there is a different and better approach to extract the fire extent as a polygon?

Comment: Have you considered using the sf package and sf objects rather than spatialpolygonsdataframes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the simple features sf library you can use functions from the tidyverse. Filtering data is a matter of using the **filter()** function. Notice that you can convert your objects to sf using **st_as_sf()**. See: https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/st_as_sf.html and [How to filter an R simple features collection using sf methods like st_intersects()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57014381/how-to-filter-an-r-simple-features-collection-using-sf-methods-like-st-intersect)

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I think I have found a way thanks to Orlandos suggestion to use *sf*.
I transformed my *large SpatialPolygonsDataFrame* object to a *sf* object via **st_as_sf()** which gave me a multipolygon. This *stf_MULTIPOLYGON* object can be subdivided into single polygons using **st_cast()** and the resulting object is subsettable like a *data.frame*.

```
bp_sf <- st_as_sf(burned_poly)
bps_sf <- st_cast(bp_sf, "POLYGON")
BpSf <- bps_sf[as.numeric(st_area(bps_sf))>=10000,]
```