# Why use st_intersection rather than st_intersects?

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sf, topology

`st_intersection` is very slow compared to `st_intersects`. So why not use the latter instead of the former? Here's an example with a small toy dataset, but the difference in execution time is huge for my actual set of just 62,020 points intersected with an actual geographic region boundary. I have 24Gb of RAM and the `st_intersects` code takes a few seconds whereas the `st_intersection` code takes more than 15 minutes (possibly much more, I haven't had the patience to wait...). Does `st_intersection` do anything that I am not getting with `st_intersects`?

The below code handles `sfc` objects but I believe would work equally for `sf` objects.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

# create square
s <- rbind(c(1, 1), c(10, 1), c(10, 10), c(1, 10), c(1, 1)) %>% list %>% st_polygon %>% st_sfc
# create random points
p <- runif(50, 0, 11) %>% cbind(runif(50, 0, 11)) %>% st_multipoint %>% st_sfc %>% st_cast("POINT")

# intersect points and square with st_intersection
st_intersection(p, s)

# intersect points and square with st_intersects (courtesy of https://stackoverflow.com/a/49304723/7114709)
p[st_intersects(p, s) %>% lengths > 0,]
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The answer is that in general the two methods do different things, though in your particular case (finding the intersection of a collection of points and a polygon), `st_intersects` can be used to efficiently do the same job.

We can show the difference with a simple example modified from your own. We start with a square:

```r
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

# create square
s <- rbind(c(1, 1), c(10, 1), c(10, 10), c(1, 10), c(1, 1)) %>% 
  list %>% 
  st_polygon %>% 
  st_sfc

plot(s)
```

[image]

Now we will create a rectangle and draw it on the same plot with a dotted outline:

```
# create rectangle
r <- rbind(c(-1, 2), c(11, 2), c(11, 4), c(-1, 4), c(-1, 2)) %>% 
  list %>% 
  st_polygon %>% 
  st_sfc

plot(r, add= TRUE, lty = 2)
```

[image]

Now we find the intersection of the two polygons and plot it in red:

```
# intersect points and square with st_intersection
i <- st_intersection(s, r)

plot(i, add = TRUE, lty = 2, col = "red")
```

[image]

When we examine the object `i`, we will see it is a new polygon:

```
i
#> Geometry set for 1 feature 
#> geometry type:  POLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: 1 ymin: 2 xmax: 10 ymax: 4
#> epsg (SRID):    NA
#> proj4string:    NA
#> POLYGON ((10 4, 10 2, 1 2, 1 4, 10 4))
```

Whereas, if we use `st_intersects`, we only get a logical result telling us whether there is indeed an intersection between `r` and `s`. If we try to use this to subset `r` to find the intersection, we don't get the intersected shape, we just get our original rectangle back:

```
r[which(unlist(st_intersects(s, r)) == 1)]
#> Geometry set for 1 feature 
#> geometry type:  POLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -1 ymin: 2 xmax: 11 ymax: 4
#> epsg (SRID):    NA
#> proj4string:    NA
#> POLYGON ((-1 2, 11 2, 11 4, -1 4, -1 2))
```

The situation that you have is different, because you are trying to find a subset of points that intersect a polygon. Is this case, the intersection of a group of points with a polygon is the same as the subset that meet the criterion `st_intersects`.

So it is great that you have found a valid way of getting a quicker intersection. Just be aware this will only work with collections of points intersecting a polygon.